# UIImageView not redrawing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I'm using code to resize a UIImageView by reducing its width to .5 its original value.
The code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.allisonHall.newWidth = .5;
    self.allisonHall.frame = CGRectMake(self.allisonHall.frame.origin.x,
                                        self.allisonHall.frame.origin.y,
                                        self.allisonHall.frame.size.width*self.allisonHall.newWidth,
                                        self.allisonHall.frame.size.height);
    self.allisonHall.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
    self.allisonHall.clipsToBounds = YES;
    NSLog(@"%f",self.allisonHall.frame.size.width);
}
```

and the result of the NSLog is 140, .5*280 as expected.
However, in the view the UIImageView remains at its original width.
The UIImageView is linked as

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet XYZdiningHall *allisonHall;
```

within the view controller's .h file, where XYZdiningHall is a subclass of UIImageView

Should the UIImageView's frame be changing given this code or do I need to call another method to fire the change?

Comment: Your resizing is trivial (it doesn't depend on any variables). If your ImageView is an IBOutlet, why not just change its size in the storyboard? If you insist on doing it programatically, there might be some auto-resizing happening after`viewDidLoad`, so you could try putting this code into `viewDidAppear:`. Don't forget to call `[super viewDidAppear:]`

Comment: Sorry, the size variable isn't trivial—I included a magic number to make the problem a little more explicit. The resizing factor is determined by a time variable.
Your fix did work, however. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, this kind of thing happens all the time. Try not to resize anything in the interface builder before `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use UIViewContentModeLeft? You can use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit or UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill and the image will be redrawn (the aspect modes are related to the image view bounds, Left isn't).